# Failed to append an element to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add the values generated by the function `calc_class`, but it is not working and I don't know the reason. I've tried to use the `numpy.append`, `numpy.insert` and the built-in Python function `append` unsuccessfully.

This is my piece of code:

```
def calc_class(test):
    expec = []
    for new in test:
        prob_vector = np.zeros((len(voc)), dtype=bool) #define a 'True' array to store class probabilities
        words_in_new = new[0].split() #split the new email into words
        words_in_new = list(set(words_in_new)) #remove duplicated words
        i = 0
        for voc_word in voc: #for each element in voc
            if voc_word in words_in_new:
                 prob_vector[i] = True #set the ith element of prob_vector to True, if voc element is in word
            else:
                prob_vector[i] = False #set the ith element of prob_vector to False, otherwise
            i += 1
        prob_ham = 1
        for i in range(len(prob_vector)):
            if prob_vector[i] == True:
                prob_ham *= ham_class_prob[i]
            else:
                prob_ham *= (1 - ham_class_prob[i])
        # alternative:     np.prod(ham_class_prob[np.where(prob_vector==True)]) * np.prod(1-  ham_class_prob[np.where(prob_vector==False)])

        prob_spam = 1
        for i in range(len(prob_vector)):
            if prob_vector[i] == True:
                prob_spam *= spam_class_prob[i]
            else:
                prob_spam *= (1 - spam_class_prob[i])

        p_spam = 0.3
        p_ham = 1 - p_spam

        p_spam_given_new = (prob_spam * p_spam) / (prob_spam * p_spam + prob_ham * p_ham)  # Bayes theorem
        print('p(spam|new_email)=', p_spam_given_new[0])
        expec.append(p_spam_given_new[0])
        print(expec)
```

The problem is that `print(expect)` is printing an empty array.

Comment: (a) The indentation shown in the question (before a third person edited it) was wrong.  Make the indentation here match the indentation in the file that you are actually using.  Don't ask us to guess what indentation you are really using. (b) `voc` is never defined. (c) In the future, before asking a question, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does the `print` right before the `append` produce anything?

Comment: There are 4 unknown variables in your code - `test`, `voc`, etc.  And the function doesn't return anything.  The `expec.append` is not the issue; just getting to that point in the function is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdb do debug (or ipdb for ipython).

```
from pdb import set_trace
```

use "set_trace()" instead of  "print('p(spam|new_email)=', p_spam_given_new[0])"(third line counted from end-line), than run your code. It will pause at this line, and you can run any python code there, such as "print(p_spam_given_new)" or just "p_spam_given_new", you can also check "prob_spam", "p_spam" or any other variable you want to check.